# Issue with adding all of the values of an array and presenting it within the array

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP script that presents of the values numValue in an array followed by adding together all of the values of `numvalue`  and presenting them as another item in the array called `sumTotal`.

**The following is the end result I am getting for the JSON array:**

```
[{"name":"person1","numValue":3.32},{"name":"person2","numValue":2.20},{"sumTotal":5}]
```

**The issue is the sumTotal does not account for decimals for some reason and instead only add the whole values like 3 and 2 shown above.**

```
[{"name":"person1","numValue":3.32},{"name":"person2","numValue":2.20},{"sumTotal":5.52}]
```

**What is done incorrectly?**

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql =  "SELECT name, SUM(value) as numvalue 
         FROM Table1
            LEFT JOIN Table2 USING(DevName)
         WHERE name <> '' 
         and name is not null
         GROUP BY name";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // you want an array of objects, so create an object to sum the sub totals
    $total = new stdClass;
    $total->sumTotal = 0;

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);

        $total->sumTotal = bcadd($total->sumTotal, $row->numvalue);
    }

    $resultArray[] = $total;
    echo json_encode($resultArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php)

> bcadd ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale = 0
>   ] ) : string

where...

> **scale** This optional parameter is used to set the number of digits
>   after the decimal place in the result. If omitted, it will default to
>   the scale set globally with the bcscale() function, or fallback to 0
>   if this has not been set.

So you should be able to fix this to 2 decimal places with using

```
bcscale(2);
```

before calling `bcadd()`.

One slight change is also that as `bcadd()` expects strings, you should change the initial value to a string...

```
$total->sumTotal = "0";
```